# How to use Debug with a trait object?

Tags: debugging, rust, traits

I want to implement the `Debug` trait on the `Post` struct, which has a trait object as a value, but I get the stack overflow error from below:

```
thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
```

```
use std::fmt::{Debug, Display, Formatter, Result as fmtResult};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Post {
    state: Option<Box<dyn State>>,
    content: String,
}

trait State {
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn content<'a>(&self, post: &'a Post) -> &'a str {
        ""
    }
}

impl Debug for dyn State {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> fmtResult {
        write!(f, "{}", self)
    }
}

impl Display for dyn State {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> fmtResult {
        write!(f, "{}", self)
    }
}
```

Comment: `write!(f, "{}", self)` in a `Display` implementation will just call itself again and again infinitely since `"{}"` will call the `Display` trait for that type.

Comment: What would be the answer on how to implement `Debug` for `Post`? @kmdreko

Comment: What do you want the output to look like when debug printing `Post`?

Comment: The elements of the `Post` struct, like {state: Some(x), content: "my string"}, but that "x" can change since it's not a concrete type but a trait object.

Comment: I'm purposely not mentioning the different types `dyn State` can be since I'm looking for the answer that might work if it's a struct with u32, i64, strings, vecs, other structs, enums...pretty much any type. Is that possible? Or do I have to implement `Debug` for every possible type due to compiling rules?

Comment: nit: not sure about the rename to `fmtResult` why not `use std::fmt::{..., self};` and `fn fmt() -> fmt::Result`⁉

Comment: It's to differentiate it from the Rust prelude's `Result`. And it's shorter and neater than writing `fmt::Result` @cafce25

Comment: It's also not adhering to Rust's naming convention. At least, name it `FmtResult`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want anything to implement `State` to also implement `Debug`, then you can do so like this:

```
trait State: Debug {
        // ^^^^^^^
    fn request_review(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    fn approve(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn State>;
    ...
}
```

Then the `#[derive(Debug)]` will work on `Post` without any manual implementations. [Full code on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6ae422b11e73f824fc2cf23becfd88ef).